# bind a Control's property to another control's property value on the same form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, controls, property-binding

I am working in C# 4.5 - Winform. My question is specific to C# WinForm.

I want to bind a Control's property to another control's property value on the same form.

I have a GroupBox and a Check Box. When Check box is checked then group box should be enabled and when CheckBox in un-checked then GroupBox should be disabled. 
However this task can be fulfilled by implement checkbox "CheckedChanged" event. But i want to accomplish this without writing any code.
I dont know it is possible or not. If possible then please provide solution.
 [image]

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern? Share some code

Comment: I dont this so, this question matters. However, No I am only using MVC pattern and working on winform.
Note : I am not working on wpf.

Comment: You would like to implement some functionality without writing a function? When you figure that out we're all out of jobs!!

Comment: @DaveParsons I dont understand what you meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do via the designer.  For your control -> Properties -> Binding...

But it is a lot of steps to result in a line of code in the designer file which you can add yourself just as easily in the constructor:

```
this.groupBox.DataBindings.Add( "Enabled", this.myCheckBox, "Checked" );
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. You actually determined what i was looking for. Thnx

Comment: I may be missing something. The designer method only allows you to bind a control's property to a data source. Unlike the coded version, which is way more flexible, allowing to bind the control's property to any object's property (optionally implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, or PropertyChanged pattern).

Comment: While you are obviously correct that manually coding gives greater control, the designer method allows a lot more power than most realize.  Through [Advanced]  you can specify or create data sources on the fly from Types in the projects, etc.  If you know enough to be comfortable manually handling that's great.